# 301 редирект через mod_rewrite на Apache

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте)
Нужен редирект:

- site.ru/article/index.php
- site.ru/article/index.html и тд.

на site.ru/article/ и соответственно с корнем site.ru/index.php то же самое.
Написал правила для mod_rewrite.

Это правило ловит все запросы вида **site.ru/article/index.php** и 301 направляет на site.ru/article/.
Но не отрабатывает на запросе site.ru/index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Это правило ловит запрос **site.ru/index.php**, и 301 направляет на **site.ru/**
Но не отлавливает редиректы с site.ru/article/index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html|htm)$ https://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

В .htaccess идут друг за другом.
Условие одно и тоже. Итоговое правило обработки разное.
Не до конца могу понять как сделал то, что работает как надо. И теперь пытаюсь понять как это уместить в одно правило.
Почему первое правило не отрабатывает на запросах к site.ru/index.php?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Теоретически должно убрать index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# первой группы захвата может и не быть, если корень сайта
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.(php|html|htm)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```